# Fatal error: Call to undefined function imap_open()

Tags: php, gmail-imap

Right gentelmen, I have been at this liturary the whole day by now I'm desperate ! Here is the situation. I am using free webhosting, whenever I try to use imap_open this message comes up : Fatal error: Call to undefined function imap_open(). I obiosly dont have any access to a server setting and it would appear that php does not have the imap module installed, even though I contacted my provider (web000) with a direct question: Do you support imap functions ? He replied yes. I did send him an email with the error message, aking him how is this possible then. Havent heard from him yet. Anyway is there anyway I could access my gmail content assuming that imap functions are undefined, is there any library I could download to get this functionality ?
Thanks for your time guys.

Comment: Did you ask if they support **PHP IMAP**? They may very well have an IMAP mail server, and that's what the tech means by "yes". You can see what's loaded into php with the `phpinfo()` function.

Comment: Im certain they do have a IMAP mail server nevertheless, I dont understand why cant I use imap functions... I think they are bloking it for free users. Thanks for your time mate

Comment: IMAP server != IMAP module in PHP. They may have the server, may not have the module (because it is free hosting, as you stated).

Comment: Yep, that is most probably the case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.read.html) to read an imap mailbox with no need for the imap extension since it's a pure php implementation (it uses sockets to connect to a mail server) of the IMAP protocol.

There is no special requirements to use Zend Framework on your host. Just download the package, extract it and upload on your hosting. I suggest you [the minimal edition](http://framework.zend.com/releases/ZendFramework-1.11.9/ZendFramework-1.11.9-minimal.zip) it's ok for running the following code.

In order to connect to a Gmail account you can start with this code, it will connect to your account, get the first message stored on server and output its subject, then you can expand it.

```
<?
// Ensure Zend folder is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    '/home/tachyon/public_html/zend/library/',
     get_include_path(),
)));

// require the ZF autoloader file if you have it in your include path
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
// if ZF is not in your path you can specify the full path
// otherwise if it's in a subdir (most likely if you're on a web hosting)
// you can do something like this
//require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Zend/Loader/AutoLoader.php';

// laod the autoloader so you don't need to require any ZF file
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

// connecting with Imap to gmail
$mail = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap(
    array(
        'host'     => 'imap.gmail.com',
        'port'     => '993',
        'ssl'      => true,
        'user'     => 'user@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'secret',
    )
);

// get the message object
$message = $mail->getMessage(1);
// output subject of message
echo $message->subject . "\n";
// dump message headers
Zend_Debug::dump($message->getHeaders());
```

I personally tested this with my Gmail account, so it's working code.

Comment: Thanks mate, I tried that as well, as I said I've been at the whole day ... Have you got any personal experiances with setting up zend. I tried to do so. My provider states on trier website that they support zend. I tried to use it but with no luck... Do you know how to include it ? I tried to download it and copy it on my server, but a need to write a htaccess file to support it i suppose ? Witch I tried and faild to do ...

Comment: I just updated my answer with some code, it should work on your hosting. You don't need to change the .htaccess file if you using just a ZF class, you will need that if you're going to use the MVC part of the framework.

Comment: Mate thank you for all your help mate, I really appreciate it, but I still cant get it to run. Here is the message I get Warning: require_once(Zend/Loader.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/tachyon/public_html/zend/library/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php on line 24
Autoloader.php is really there and gets called, but the problem is that then autoloader.php calls loader.php with a incorrect path

Comment: I forgotten to set the include path, try now with the updated code.

Comment: Fabio mate you are star, cant tank you enough

Comment: Sory mate, Im completly new to the forum, I believe its done now, grazie very much again